# ​automorphism group of rational numbers

Tags: group-theory, automorphism-group

Let $G=(\Bbb Q\setminus\{{0\}},∗)$ be a group of the rational numbers under multiplication. How to find the structure of ${\rm Aut}(G)$?

I show that if $f$ is a automorphism then it maps a  basis of $G$ to another basis.

Conversely a automorphism can be constructed given a mapping between two basis.

Obviously the set of prime numbers is a basis, so I want to find all basis of this group. But such basis are not just prime numbers (for example, you can make $x_n$ the product of the first n prime numbers, so that the elements also form a basis).

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Hint: The group you describe is a [free abelian group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_abelian_group) whose basis is the set of primes. Does that help?

Comment: I know this. But I think I should find out all the basis of the group, and I can't do that.

Comment: I just told you: The basis is the set of primes. Each element of your group may be written as a product of zero or more prime powers (including negative prime powers), and this decomposition is linear over multiplication.

Comment: I'm sorry but still don't understand how what you are saying relates to solving this problem. I have added something to the problem. Can you elaborate more?